# Concrete5 5.6.3.4 User is Logged in as Wrong User

Tags: hash, authentication, session-cookies, concrete5

We have had an intermittent issue with Users of our site mysteriously being logged in as a different user.  The site is built on Concrete5 Version 5.6.3.4.  This seems to be a huge security flaw as we are displaying private and sensitive data and allowing for onsite credit card purchases.

Answer (score 0):

The site implements forever cookies which seems to be causing the issue.  According to [this](https://github.com/concrete5/concrete5-legacy/issues/1921), the collision rate for the hash used for the cookie is around 8%. The patch in the link on that page seems to mitigate the problem but not completely eliminate it.

The second patch attempts to add the user id to the identifier in order to make it unique and eliminate that collision risk.  Seems like it should read:

```
public function getString($length = 12) {
    $str = str_repeat($this->letters, 10);
-       $hash = substr(str_shuffle($str), 0, $length);
+       $user = new User();
+       if($user->getUserID()) {
+           $hash = sprintf("%i:%s, $user->getUid(), substr(str_shuffle($str), 0, $length));
+       } else {
+           $hash = sprintf("%s%i:%s", substr(str_shuffle($str), 0, $length), mt_rand(999,9999), substr(str_shuffle($str), 0, $length));
```